# discord.js - Leaderboard / top command showing wrong order

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, discord.js

I have been having a lot of trouble recently with a leader board command showing users in the wrong order.

I am using the DiscordJS master branch and Sequelize v6

Here is an image of what I am describing:
[image: Leaderboard]

> Leaderboard command file:

```js
const { MessageEmbed } = require("discord.js");

exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
    const { Users } = require("../functions/database");

    let users = await Users.findAll({ limit: 10, order: [['count', 'DESC']] });
    for (const user of users) {
        await client.users.fetch(user.userid);
    }
    let embed = new MessageEmbed()
        .setAuthor("Middleman Leaderboard", `${client.user.displayAvatarURL({ dynamic: true })}`)
        .setDescription(users.map((user, position) => `**${position + 1}**. ${(client.users.cache.get(user.userid).username)}: ${user.count} Points`))
        .setThumbnail('https://i.ibb.co/ByRSBmB/hp.png')
        .setColor("#d70069");
    await message.reply(embed)
}
```

> Sequelize database model:

```js
const Users = sequelize.define('users', {
    userid: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    },
    count: Sequelize.INTEGER,
});

exports.Users = Users;
```

Please note this is greatly a proof of concept and not for production.
Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a solution from discordjs.guide:

```js
users.sort((a, b) => b.balance - a.balance)
        .filter(user => client.users.cache.has(user.user_id))
        .first(10)
        .map((user, position) => `(${position + 1}) ${(client.users.cache.get(user.user_id).tag)}: ${user.balance}`)
        .join('\n'),
```

Comment: I honestly have no idea how this fled my mind beforehand, I remembered trying it and it did not work! I guess I was trying to use .sort on the Object (Users).

This did the trick, thanks a lot!